# Pre-define groups for PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

my_events table stores event_id, event_date, event_type, event_duration.

There are many event types for example: Event A, Event B, Event C, Event D
The query that I have written will get my results but will exclude events that were not in my observation period event_date > '2023-05-01'

How do I get the results so that the grouping will show all Events in the first column?

This query will return only events that have occurred after '2023-05-01'
for example:

```
SELECT event_type,
COUNT(event_id) as num_events,
AVG(event_duration) as avg_duration
FROM my_events
WHERE event_date > '2023-05-01'
GROUP BY event_type
```

| event_type | num_events | avg_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event B | 20 | 00:33:25 |
| Event C | 33 | 01:04:22 |

I want the results to show A and D even if they do not occur in my observation period:

| event_type | num_events | avg_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | 0 | 00:00:00 |
| Event B | 20 | 00:33:25 |
| Event C | 33 | 01:04:22 |
| Event D | 0 | 00:00:00 |

Additional information based on responses:
The table is very large and I would like to stick to pre-defining a list of rows of events.
My next attempt was to create a Common Table Expression and left join my_events onto the CTE as shown

```
WITH event_list
     AS (SELECT 'Event A' AS event_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Event B' AS event_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Event C' AS event_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Event D' AS event_type)
SELECT el.event_type,
       Count(me.event_id)     AS num_events,
       Avg(me.event_duration) AS avg_duration
FROM   event_list el
       LEFT JOIN my_events me using (event_type)
WHERE  me.event_date > '2023-05-01'
GROUP  BY el.event_type
```

However, if I run the CTE alone it displays the rows for Events A-D, but after joining it with my_events I still get the same result of just B and C.

Comment: Your last attempt doesn't work because your WHERE clause removes the NULL-extended rows your LEFT JOIN just fabricated.  Either move the condition from the WHERE to the ON, or rewrite it to `me.event_date is NULL or me.event_date > '2023-05-01'`

Comment: I suggest adding an `event_types` table and a foreign key constraint on `my_events.event_type` referencing that table. The query could then use the `event_types` table instead of hard-coding the values in the query. This change would insulate the query from changes to event types. This is just a possible improvement of the data model, it's not related to the missing rows.

Comment: Instead if using the `UNION ALL` pattern, the CTE can be written more concisely as `WITH event_list(event_type) AS (VALUES ('Event A'), ('Event B'), ('Event C'), ('Event D'))`.

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns the requested results:

```
WITH event_types AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT event_type
    FROM my_events
)
SELECT event_types.event_type,
       COUNT(my_events.event_id) AS num_events,
       COALESCE(AVG(my_events.event_duration), INTERVAL '0' SECOND) AS avg_duration
  FROM event_types
  LEFT JOIN my_events
    ON event_types.event_type = my_events.event_type
      AND my_events.event_date > '2023-05-01'::DATE
 GROUP BY event_types.event_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all distinct `event_type`'s and then use subqueries to collect `num_events` and `avg_duration`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT event_type, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_events WHERE event_type = events.event_type AND event_date > '2023-05-01') AS num_events, 
(SELECT AVG(event_duration) FROM my_events WHERE event_type = events.event_type AND event_date > '2023-05-01') AS avg_duration 
FROM my_events AS events;
```

If you need to get `00:00:00` in `avg_duration` instead of `NULL`'s, then use `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT event_type, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_events WHERE event_type = events.event_type AND event_date > '2023-05-01') AS num_event, 
COALESCE((SELECT AVG(event_duration) FROM my_events WHERE event_type = events.event_type AND event_date > '2023-05-01'), '00:00:00') AS avg_duration 
FROM my_events AS events;
```

Comment: For this task, using subqueries in the select list is inefficient both in terms of execution and coding. The subqueries are executed for each row. There is a lot of redundant code because the search criteria is repeated for each subquery.